# Replacing colon by double backslash

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to replace `:` with double backslash `\\` but the code below is ignoring one slash.

```
var original_id = $j(element).attr('id'); // e.g. sub:777

var new_id = original_id.split(":");

new_id = new_id.join("\\:");

alert(new_id);
```

Instead of displaying `sub\\:777`, `sub\:777` is displayed. The code is ignoring one `\` slash.

I would appreciate it if somebody could show me my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must escape the backslashes:

```
new_id = new_id.join("\\\\:");
```

See [JavaScript Special Characters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp) for some details.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is used as an escape character in many languages for things like `\n` for new line.  The reason why you see one is because it is escaped by the first `\`.  (otherwise it would be invisible to you).  To remedy this, escape two `\`s like so:  `"\\\\:"`